# Character Pointers with Palindrome Checker in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, palindrome

This is code I wrote that checks if a string is a palindrome or not. I need to revise this code so that it uses character pointers in it. Could someone give me some suggestions/tips...or show me how to do that? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    char string1[20];
    int i, length;
    int flag = 0;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", string1);
    length = strlen(string1);
    for(i=0;i < length ;i++){
        if(toupper(string1[i]) != toupper(string1[length-i-1])){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag) 
        printf("%s is not a palindrome \n\n", string1); 
    else 
        printf("%s is a palindrome \n", string1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char` pointer. dynamic allocation??

Comment: How exactly you should use "pointers" here? instead of `[]` operator? assignment focused on pointer arithmetic?

Comment: And also this seems to be too trivial problem. It looks like you rather need a book than asking it here.

Comment: Side note: Think about the logic. Is it required to traverse the entire string to know it's palindrome or not ?

Answer (score 2):

In your code you use `string1[i]` to access the current element from the beginning of the string, and `string1[length-i-1]` to access the current element from the end of the string. You could create two pointers, `pb` and `pe`, and then move them toward each other.

To define pointers, use this:

```
char *pb = &string1[0]; // Or just string1, compiler will convert it to pointer
char *pe = &string1[length-1];
```

To advance the pointers toward each other, use `pb++` and `pe--`.
To see if the pointers have not crossed each other , check that `pb < pe`. Currently, your program checks the string twice; there's no need to do that - you can stop as soon as `pe` becomes less than or equal to the `pb`.
To access the character pointed to by the current pointer, use

```
toupper(*pb) != toupper(*pe)
```

You can combine the check with advancing the pointers, like this:

```
toupper(*pb++) != toupper(*pe--)
```

Note: it is not safe to use `%s`, because when users enter more characters than fits in your `string1` buffer overrun results. You should specify the length of the buffer, like this:

```
scanf("%19s", string1); // Leave one char for null terminator
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but I think this answers it.  You actually are using character pointers.  char string1[20] is the same as char *string1. The difference is that you've basically assigned the pointer to a block of memory.  You could access the string in this way.

```
char string[20] = "foo";

printf("%c\n", string[0]);  // will print 'f'
printf("%c\n", *string); // will also print 'f'

printf("%c\n", string[1]); // will print the first 'o'
printf("%c\n", *(string + 1)); // will also print the first 'o'
```

Answer (score 0):

with char * it goes like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char string1[20];
    int i, length;
    int flag = 0;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", string1);
    length = strlen(string1);

    char *start=string1;
    char *end=&string1[length-1];

    //only check upto half


    for(i=0;i <= (length-1)/2 ;i++)
    {
        if(toupper(*(start+i)) != toupper(*(end-i)))
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag) 
        printf("%s is not a palindrome \n\n", string1); 
    else 
        printf("%s is a palindrome \n", string1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cant we just copy the original string to another array, and then use strrev() to reverse the copied string and then finally compare the original string with the reversed string?

Like this

```
1.get new string 
2.copy string to new array 
3.reverse the copied string using strrev 
4.use strcmp to check if both are same or not?
```

this seemed easier
(i am a beginner so please correct me if i am wrong)